# System Time - User Input Time Help (Java)

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have an alarm clock program that I need help with. What I need help with is to subtract the computer system time from the user time they entered in the program. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what is needed to get it fixed.

Thanks in advance!

Sean

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class AlarmClock
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException
{

    int retry = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sean\nListing 4.14 P. 163\nAlarm Clock", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    while (retry == JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)
    {
        // Current time
          Date dNow = new Date( );
          SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat (" MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");

          String userTime;

          // Asking user for the date and time
          userTime = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a date, time and AM or PM:\n Example: 09/12/2013 11:00:00 PM");
          SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a ");

          //String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58";
          //String dateStop = "01/14/2012 10:31:48";

          // Computing the computer time and user time to see when the alarm will end
          Date d1 = null;
          Date d2 = null;

            try 
                {
                    d1 = format.parse(dNow);
                    d2 = format.parse(userTime);

                    // In milliseconds
                    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
                    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
                    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
                    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
                    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            // Reporting when the alarm will hit

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,diffDays + " days, " + diffHours + " hours, " + diffMinutes + " minutes, " + diffSeconds + " seconds" );
                } 
                catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

        // Asking the user if they like to set up another alarm
        retry = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to set another alarm?", "Question", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    }
        // Good Bye Message
    final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-PsxZ4-C4Jss/UOSc0sDFpPI/AAAAAAAABLQ/nZSkY95cL48/s320/goodbye.jpg"));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for using the Alarm Clock Program!", "Good Bye", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your application? (I don't mean this in a demeaning way but there might be a better way to do whatever it is you are trying to accomplish)

Comment: *Sign* Its an alarm clock.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: User enters time and date for an alarm. The program will tell you go much longer till that alarm goes off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this line

```
d1 = format.parse(dNow);
```

doesn't make any sense (and, actually, doesn't compile) because `dNow` is a `Date` object, and you would only need to parse a `String`.

Also, your date format line creates an unnecessary space that is ruining your parser.

Change

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a ");
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
```

And your parse should work.

Comment: Thanks! Then wouldn't I just subtract user time from dNow or no?

Comment: Yep just change `d1 = dNow` then subtract `d2` - `d1`.

Answer (score 0):

dNow is already a Date object, you don't need to use format.parse to convert it from a String to a Date.

If this doesn't help, please post your error message or the incorrect output.